# python print before cmd prompt

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm using the `cmd` module to create an interactive shell which wraps a serial port in my custom protocol. I have it wrapping the user input and sending out of the UART, and receiving and parsing the serial input (on a separate thread). What I would like to do is 'insert' the received (parsed) messages above the current prompt whenever they are received, rather than after the next command. If I just print, it writes it from where the cursor currently is, and 'destroys' the current prompt. Would it possible clear the current line, print my received message and then recreate the current prompt and whatever was written.

Comment: Can you give a code example? It is hard (at least for me) to understand what you are trying to do.